# Directly referring to Pivot column to allow ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How do you go about referring to a pivoted column name so that you can include `ISNULL` around it? In my example below I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name '1234'.

The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
    (SELECT  
         ISNULL([1234], 0) as test1,
         *
     FROM   
         [Report]('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')) a 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(amount) 
        FOR account IN ([1234])
    ) p
```

Comment: you already alias the column `[1234]` as `test1` in the sub-query `a`. So you should reference the alias name in the pivot query

Comment: Sorry @Squirrel, but I'm confused with your comment. Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sub-query `a` `ISNULL([1234], 0) as test1`, you have alias the name to `test1`

So in the `pivot` query, you should use the alias name `test1` and not `[1234]`

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT  
    ISNULL([1234], 0) as test1,
    *
  FROM [Report]('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
) a 
PIVOT (
  SUM(amount) 
  FOR account IN ([test1])    -- change to `test1` here
) p
```